# HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 install Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, boot, operating-system

I purchased recent an `HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8` and a `Windows Server 2008` designed for HP Servers and when I want to install the OS (Windows Server 2008) on My Server I receive following error:

> A required CD/DVD drive device is missing. If you have a driver floppy
>   disk, CD,DVD, of USB flash drive, please insert it now. Note: If the
>   Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely
>   remove it from this step.

I was try to add chipset driver from stick, but the installer doesn't recognize it.

Thanks

Comment: You've not put enough information here; are you installing from DVD and if so are you using one of the internal HP drives? Also have you looked at the boot config - I suspect you just need to put the DVD drive ahead of the disk controller in the boot sequence.

Answer (score -2):

You canrun  BIOS setting and select SATA for controller choice.. This would boot your server with sata disks configuration and you caould install windows ; then configure - if needed yur RAID and other settings